# SELECT Error Cassandra 'Row' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: select, docker, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to setup and run Cassandra 3.10 in my local docker (https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/). Everything goes well until I try to select from one table.

This is the error I get everytime I run select whatever from whatever:

```
'Row' object has no attribute 'values'
```

The steps that I followed:

1. I created a new keyspace using the default superuser: cassandra.  create `keyspace test with replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor' : 2};` and `USE test;`
2. I created a new table: `create table usertable (userid int primary key, usergivenname varchar, userfamilyname varchar, userprofession varchar);`
3. Insert some data: `insert into usertable (userid, usergivenname, userfamilyname, userprofession) values (1, 'Oliver', 'Veits', 'Freelancer');`
4. Try to select: `select * from usertable where userid = 1;`

I got this steps from: https://oliverveits.wordpress.com/2016/12/08/cassandra-hello-world-example/ just to copy & paste some working code (I was getting mad with the syntax and typos)

This are the logs of my docker image:

```
INFO  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-04-23 19:09:12,543 MigrationManager.java:303 - Create new Keyspace: KeyspaceMetadata{name=test2, params=KeyspaceParams{durable_writes=true, replication=ReplicationParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy, replication_factor=2}}, tables=[], views=[], functions=[], types=[]}
INFO  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-04-23 19:09:41,415 MigrationManager.java:343 - Create new table: org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@1b484e82[cfId=6757f460-2858-11e7-9787-6d2c86545d91,ksName=test2,cfName=usertable,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.1, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=864000, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@4bce743f, extensions={}, cdc=false},comparator=comparator(),partitionColumns=[[] | [userfamilyname usergivenname userprofession]],partitionKeyColumns=[userid],clusteringColumns=[],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type,columnMetadata=[usergivenname, userprofession, userid, userfamilyname],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]]
INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2017-04-23 19:09:41,484 ColumnFamilyStore.java:406 - Initializing test2.usertable
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2017-04-23 19:13:25,214 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:75 - Redistributing index summaries
```

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**

I created another table with a uuid column like this: "uid uuid primary key". It works when the table is empty but after one insert, I get the same error

Comment: Try `\sudo pip install cassandra-driver --upgrade`

Comment: Hi @AshrafulIslam , thanks but still same problem

Comment: The problem is in the cqlsh, your cassandra is ok. By the way which os are you using ?

Comment: Hi again @AshrafulIslam , I'm using ubuntu 16.04. I tried with other versions of Cassandra (even version 2) but I have the same problem. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, I was using cqlsh. You just need to reload. Probably, it is a cqlsh bug the first time or after create a schema.

```
~$ sudo docker run --name ex1 -d  cassandra:latest                                 
9c1092938d29ec7f94bee773cc2adc0a23ff09344e32500bfeb1898466610d06
~$ sudo docker exec -ti ex1 /bin/bash                                         
root@9c1092938d29:/# cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> CREATE SCHEMA simple1 
   ... WITH replication={
   ... 'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
   ... 'replication_factor':1};
cqlsh> use simple1;
cqlsh:simple1> create table users(id varchar primary key, first_name varchar, last_name varchar);
cqlsh:simple1> select * from users;

 id | first_name | last_name
----+------------+-----------

(0 rows)
cqlsh:simple1> insert into users(id, first_name, last_name) values ('U100001', 'James', 'Jones');
cqlsh:simple1> select * from users;
'Row' object has no attribute 'values'
cqlsh:simple1> quit


root@9c1092938d29:/# cqlsh     
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> use simple1;
cqlsh:simple1> select * from users;

 id      | first_name | last_name
---------+------------+-----------
 U100001 |      James |     Jones

(1 rows)
```

Comment: I was getting the error `'Row' object has no attribute 'keys'`. Reloading solved the problem.